# Clojure transform map values which are vectors to set

Tags: clojure

I am new at Clojure. I have a map like

```
{:title "The Little Schemer"
 :authors [friedman , felleisen]}
```

I want to transform it to:

```
{:title "The Little Schemer"
 :authors #{friedman , felleisen}}
```

I attempted like:

```
(def friedman {:name "Daniel Friedman" :birth-year 1944})
(def felleisen {:name "Matthias Felleisen"})

(defn old-book->new-book [book]
  (set  (:authors book)
        )
  )

(println (old-book->new-book {:title "The Little Schemer"
                              :authors [friedman , felleisen]}))

; => Output: #{{:name Daniel Friedman, :birth-year 1944} {:name Matthias Felleisen}}
; => Expected-Output: #{friedman , felleisen}
```

Here the `defs` `friedman` and `felleisen` gets executed and there results are getting transformed to set. But, I want the function names to be converted to set instead of their results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to `println` this:

```
(println {:title "The Little Schemer"
      :authors [friedman , felleisen]})
```

The output will be:

```
{:title The Little Schemer, :authors [{:name Daniel Friedman, :birth-year 1944} {:name Matthias Felleisen}]}
```

So, what happened here? As You know in this context `friedman` and `felleisen` is a variables, so, if You print them - they will be appear in a print message by values. For example:

```
(def a 1)
(println a)
```

Will print `1`, because of `a` is just a variable.

**The code which you shown here do what You want and when you print it - then values of variable of `friedman` and `felleisen` substitute by values.**

Your vector of autors(`(:authors [friedman felleisen])`) after disposing the function `set` will be converted to a `set`, what we saw from Your output.